# Apache Ignite server crashes after incorporating Auditing events

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, ignite

In start, it works fine, but after a certain time (1-2 hours) it crashes with the following exception in server logs.

ERROR 1 --- [-ignite-server%]                                          : JVM will be halted immediately due to the failure: [failureCtx=FailureContext [type=CRITICAL_ERROR, err=class o.a.i.i.IgniteDeploymentCheckedException: Failed to obtain deployment for class: com.event.audit.AuditEventListener$$Lambda$1484/0x0000000800a7ec40]]

```java
public static void remoteListener(Ignite ignite) {
    // This optional local callback is called for each event notification


    // that passed remote predicate listener.
    IgniteBiPredicate<UUID, CacheEvent> locLsnr = new IgniteBiPredicate<UUID, CacheEvent>() {
      @Override public boolean apply(UUID nodeId, CacheEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("Listener caught an event");

        //--- My custom code to persists the event in another cache
    };

    IgnitePredicate<CacheEvent> remoteListener = cacheEvent -> {
      return true;
    };

    // Register event listeners on all nodes to listen for task events.
    UUID lsnrId = ignite.events(ignite.cluster()).remoteListen(locLsnr, remoteListener, EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT, EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any thread dumps or any stack trace in logs?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you, you try to perform cache operations in event listener:

> //--- My custom code to persists the event in another cache

Event listeners are called under the locks and this is bad idea to make any other cache operations in listeners. I suppose it could be the root cause of your issue.

Try to change you design, for example you can add your caught event in a queue and then read this queue in another thread and save the data in another cache.

Comment: Yes, the server is not crashing any more, what I did, I performed cache operations in a separate thread other than event listener function itself. One more question, when event listener is called, the whole server caches are locked or that specific cache is locked against which the event was captured.

Comment: It should be per-cache behaviour. In the meantime, you might check the continuous queries feature which is quite similar to the events but behaves in an async manner (allowing user code in a listener thread). You can read more here: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/key-value-api/continuous-queries